# An Old Tandem. Need to Know the Maker

Tags: frames

I have an old Tandem Frame. The identification is the Number 311. Is it possible to identify the manufacturer just from this information

Comment: No, thats way too little information. But if you put pictures and look for other identifying marks, people might be able to help.

Comment: Please add clear and well-lit photos of your tandem.   From supplied information, we couldn't even tell you how many wheels it has or what colour it is.

Answer (score 3):

No. That kind of serial number hints at a small builder who just numbers all their frames sequentially, which is a practice any number of them have used.

Comment: while this does technically answer the question, and it might even count as useful in that we can mark all future "can you identify this bike (with no useful information" questions as duplicates, I still think it's a poor answer and the question should instead be closed.